# Skeleton css columns

Tags: css

I have recently discovered skeleton.css and it is exactly what I was looking for.  I didn't quite understand columns, but the example for buttons did exactly what I wanted as far as stacking elements as the screen narrows.  What I have works beautifully, but I am not yet savvy enough with css to make the buttons into columns.  The html and css code I have cut down to just what works.  Any suggestions as to how to convert buttons to columns would be greatly appreciated.

My code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="description" content="None">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//127.0.0.1/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//127.0.0.1/css/skeleton.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="border:1px solid red;">
<div>
<a class="button" href="#">Would like column 1</a>
<button>Would like column 2</button>
<input value="Would like column 3" type="submit">
<input value="Would like column 4" type="button">
<input value="Would like column 5" type="button">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

/* css */

.container {
position: relative; 
width: 80%; 
max-width: 960px; 
margin: 0 auto; 
padding: 0; }
.container .columns { 
float: left; 
width: 100%; 
box-sizing: border-box; }

/* For devices larger than 550px */
@media (min-width: 550px) {

.container .columns {
margin-left: 4%; }
}

html { 
font-size: 62.5%; } 
body {
font-size: 1.5em; 
line-height: 1.6;
font-weight: 400;
font-family: "Raleway", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, ans-serif;
color: #222; }

a { 
color: #1EAEDB; }
a:hover { 
color: #0FA0CE;
}

.button,
button,
input[type="submit"],
input[type="button"] {
display: inline-block;
background-color: transparent;
border-radius: 4px;
color: #555;
text-align: center;
font-size: 11px;
font-weight: 600;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
border: 1px solid #bbb;
height: 38px;
width:188px;
line-height: 38px;
padding: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
button {
margin-bottom: 0;
}
.container:after,
.row:after/**,
.u-cf**/ { 
content: "";
display: table;
clear: both;
}
/* Larger than mobile */
@media (min-width: 400px) {}

/* Larger than phablet (also point when grid becomes active) */
@media (min-width: 550px) {}

/* Larger than tablet */
@media (min-width: 750px) {}

/* Larger than desktop */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {}

/* Larger than Desktop HD */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}
```

Comment: convert buttons to columns? or fo u want to put the buttons in columns

Comment: The button code happened to be the code that collapsed correctly in the skeleton examples.  I would just like columns - no buttons.

Comment: But u have given the items the button class

Comment: What r u looking for , question not clear

Comment: I'm looking for code for 5 columns that works as well as the button code.

Comment: I decided to play with it myself and replaced the inputs with divs and changed the css accordingly.  The code below will produce five equal width columns which will stack in four stages as the screen narrows.  It works perfectly for what I need and was pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to play with it myself and replaced the inputs with divs and changed the css accordingly.  The code below will produce five equal width columns which will stack in four stages as the screen narrows.  It works perfectly for what I need and was pretty simple.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<meta name="description" content="None">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//127.0.0.1/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//127.0.0.1/css/skeleton2.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="border:1px solid red;">

<div class="column">Column 1<br>More stuff here</div>
<div class="column">Column 2</div>
<div class="column">Column 3</div>
<div class="column">Column 4</div>
<div class="column">Column 5</div> 

</div>
</body>
</html>

.container {
position: relative; 
width: 90%; 
max-width: 960px; 
margin: 0 auto; 
padding: 0;
}

/* For devices larger than 550px */
@media (min-width: 550px) {
html { 
font-size: 62.5%; } 
body {
font-size: 1.5em; /* currently ems cause chrome bug misinterpreting rems on body element */
font-weight: 400;
font-family: "Raleway", "HelveticaNeue", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
color: #000;
}

.column {
display: inline-block;
width:188px;
vertical-align: text-top;
padding-left: 10px;
white-space: nowrap;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Larger than mobile */
@media (min-width: 400px) {}

/* Larger than phablet (also point when grid becomes active) */
@media (min-width: 550px) {}

/* Larger than tablet */
@media (min-width: 750px) {}

/* Larger than desktop */
@media (min-width: 1000px) {}

/* Larger than Desktop HD */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {}
```